# How to project a spherical map onto a sphere / cube

Tags: transformation, spherical-geometry

I have this panorama, an spherical map from google streetview, and want to map this on a sphere/cube. Below are some examples and illustrations, i am going to implement it in c++ and are not sure where to start.

[image: panorama]

I tried http://krpano.com/docu/tutorials/quickstart/#top that gives the results listed at the bottom. It illustrates what i want, but the rotation axis is off. I need to create the views of direct ahead and back, left and right. Ideal i would like to map it to the sphere and tell it what angles to extract (the orientation of the cube).

[Back,Down,Front,Left,Right,Up]

[image: Back]
[image: Down]
[image: Font]
[image: Left]
[image: Right]
[image: Up]

Comment: Looks like an inverse mercator projection will map the picture to a sphere. http://mathworld.wolframcom/MercatorProjection.html

Comment: Are you able to outline how i can use the mercator projection to create the four views like above ?